# Retrieve load address of unloaded shared library from linux core dump

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, glibc, coredump

A linux process appears to unload a shared library using `dlclose` while still having its functions registered as callbacks. It crashes later when the callback is called which is now invalid memory, and gdb can't unwind the stack because of it.

Short of the application explicitly storing a list of shared libraries as they are loaded, is there a way to get from the core dump the load addresses for libraries that were unloaded (at least ones loaded via `dlopen`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to get from the core dump the load addresses for libraries that were unloaded

No. The `core` is an in-memory image of the process at the time of the crash, and the info about libraries that were unloaded is *no longer there* -- there is no reason for the runtime loader to keep that info around.

However, you can *probably* guess it.

Suppose your code looks like this:

```
  void *h = dlopen("somelib.so", ...);
  some_struct.callback = (int(*)(void)) dlsym(h, "some_func");
  dlclose(h);  // Oops. some_struct.callback will crash if called
```

In the `core` dump / GDB you should know the value of `.callback`. Let's say it's `p == 0x7f...1234`.

You also know the address `addr` of `some_func` in `libsomelib.so` (from `nm libsomelib.so | grep some_func`).

The load address is then `p - addr`, and you can use GDB `add-symbol-file /path/to/libsomelib.so load_address` to let GDB know where `libsomelib.so` used to be.

Note however, that the `load_address` GDB wants is *not* `p - addr`; it's `p - addr + &.text-in-libsomelib.so`. You can find the address of `.text` with `readelf -WS libsomelib.so | grep '\.text'`